# After updating to latest Spring boot version, spring-boot-starter-parent 2.6.2, my tests stop executing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j

I have updated the Spring boot version to **2.6.2** from **2.3.12.RELEASE** to incorporate log4j change. Now when I executed mvn clean install to build my code, it is executing only one unit test. I have a test suite of around 423 tests that are all executing and passing with 2.3.12.RELEASE. But now even tests are not executing fine. I haven't seen any such incident reported so I am reporting one.

I am executing my tests with PowerMockRunner

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

PowerMock dependencies

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
   <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
   <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Springboot 2.4 they removed JUnit4. If you're using JUnit4 you need to add this dependency in your pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Though after adding this dependency, the test class execution started...but several of them are failing. Any solution for that ?

Comment: I had the same problem when switching to sb 2.4, adding that dependency solved for me.   I also removed test.mv.db  and  test.trace.db, maybe should help.

Answer (score 0):

What version of maven you are using and have you use the junit maven plugin.

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
   <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
   <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: This isn't an answer but rather a comment.