# Junit (4.12) is not executing after spring-boot 2.6.2 migration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit4

I have migrated from Spring to Spring-boot version 2.6.2. mvn clean install is successful but none of the junit(version 4.12) is executing. After few research I got to know that Spring-boot 2.4 onwards, JUnit4 has been removed. I tried below solutions which didn't work.

[After updating to latest Spring boot version, spring-boot-starter-parent 2.6.2, my tests stop executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70531671/after-updating-to-latest-spring-boot-version-spring-boot-starter-parent-2-6-2)

[Spring Boot maven unit tests not being executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51270218/spring-boot-maven-unit-tests-not-being-executed/62121099)

Comment: Simply migrate to JUnit 5.  It been a while it has been released.

Comment: Add junit-jupiter dependency to your project and junit-jupiter-vintage https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4

Answer (score 10):

**JUnit 5 = JUnit Platform + JUnit Jupiter + JUnit Vintage.**

Refer to: [Junit5 doc](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-what-is-junit-5)

If you import junit-jupiter by depending on latest spring-boot-starter-test, it will only run the Junit5 style test cases. So Junit provides junit-vintage to run old Junit3/Junit4 cases and by default it's not contained in the spring-boot-starter-test dependencies.
So there are two solutions to keep running Junit4:

1. Depend on both of junit-jupiter and junit-vintage to support all Junit3/4/5 cases.

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   ```
2. Exclude junit-jupiter from spring-boot-starter-test to run Junit4

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
   ```

Comment: Along with this, upgrade powermock related dependency or exclude JUnit 4 dependency from that

Answer (score 3):

Exclude the junit-jupiter-engine and junit-vintage-engine from the spring-boot-starter-test dependency and then add JUnit 4 dependency in your pom:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This helped me. Can you pls explain this?

Answer (score 0):

As of SpringBoot V2.2, Spring only support Junit 5 by default and have removed backward compatibility with JUnit 4.
It clearly states that in Spring 2.2 release notes :
[https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#junit-5)

"You can’t use the junit-vintage-engine and you’ll need to explicitly roll back to JUnit 4:"

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Springboot 2.4 release notes mentions this POM dependency change :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes#junit-5s-vintage-engine-removed-from-spring-boot-starter-test

Answer (score 0):

I can run both `JUnit4`/`JUnit5` using `Spring Boot 3`(This will work for `Spring Boot 2.x.x` as well)

#### Step 1 (I am using Gradle as build tool, but Maven would be similar):

```
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine") //This is for Junit4
```

#### Step 2

```
package com.example;

//Change the imports accordingly to toggle between JUnit4/5
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ATest {
     @Test
     public void test01() {
          assertEquals("Optimizer", "Optimizer");
     }
}
```